# When is the homomorphic image of a Fuchsian group into ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ Fuchsian?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $G$ be a Fuchsian group, by which we mean a discrete subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Or equivalently: $G$ is a subgroup of the automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$ which acts properly discontinuously.

Let $\phi: G\to{\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ be a homomorphism. When can we say $\phi(G)$ is also Fuchsian?

I believe it's not true in general, but I've been having trouble constructing a counterexample. Here's what I have so far:

Let's suppose $G$ is finitely generated with at least two generators $g_1,g_2$, and suppose further there is no relation between them. Define $\phi(g_1)$ to be $z\mapsto z+1$ and $\phi(g_2)\mapsto kz$ for $0<k<1$, and then send everything else in $G\setminus \langle g_1,g_2\rangle$ to the identity. I believe(?) this gives a well-defined homomorphism by extending in the natural way. The image $\phi(G)$ is not Fuchsian then since one can construct indiscrete orbits (for example, $\phi(G)\cdot i$ includes points of the form $i+mk^n$, and so $i$ is not isolated in the orbit).

There seems to be issues with this idea though. For one thing, one can't send the generators of $G$ to elements of arbitrary type. For example, if $g\in G$ is elliptic and of finite order, then $\phi(g)$ must be elliptic as well. It would also be nice to not have to assume $G$ is finitely generated, or make arbitrary assumptions about the generators. Does anyone have a more general construction?

A softer question: what conditions can be imposed to ensure that $\phi(G)$ is Fuchsian? Does assuming $G$ is, e.g., nonelementary and elliptic-free win you anything? Or does one need to impose restrictions on $\phi$ (say, make it continuous)?

Comment: Examples are easy to construct, just take any homomorphism of free group such that one of the generators maps to an elliptic element of infinite order. Once you assume that $G$ is finitely generated, there are various algorithmic criteria for discreteness of subgroups of $PSL(2,R)$.

Comment: And, yes, a nonelementary subgroup of $PSL(2,R)$ containing no elliptic elements is necessarily discrete.

Comment: The full answer to your question is quite complicated and depends on which abstract group you are asking about. I would suggest narrowing the scope of your question. For instance, if $G$ isomorphic to the rank $2$ free group, and discreteness of images of homomorphisms $F_2 \mapsto PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ is a complicated subject; see [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96469/matrices-generating-non-discrete-subgroups-of-sl2-r), in particular the references to Gilman's book.

Comment: If on the other hand $G$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a closed, oriented surface of genus $g$, there is a lot of information in Goldman's thesis, which you can also be referred to in that same MathOverflow link.

Comment: Thanks! The surface fundamental group case was actually exactly the case I am most interested in, so the reference to Goldman's thesis is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, just too long for a comment.

Any map from a Fuchsian group is continuous, as the topology on the group is discrete. Requiring that the homomorphism is a homeomorphism on its image is clearly sufficient, as being Fuchsian is a purely topological property.

Being a discrete subgroup is a strong condition, as the group structure forces the group to be *uniformly* discrete, i.e. there is a radius such that a ball of this radius around *any* point in the group intersects the group only in that point. Thus, you can reduce to trying to find some Fuchsian group that contains in its image a non-repeating sequence in $PSL_2(\Bbb{R})$ that approaches $I$. In a Fuchsian group, any sequence approaching $I$ must eventually be constant $I$, so this would show the claim.

This is difficult, and might be impossible. For example, there is no matrix $A\neq I$ such that $A^n\to I$ (this can be shown by an eigenvalue argument), so there is no hope that $\Bbb{Z}$, embedded as a Fuchsian group, could map to something non-Fuchsian.